# Arduino Esplora continous input stream Java

Tags: java, arduino

I'm new to Arduino and I enjoy programming in Java. I recently bought an Arduino Esplora and want to communicate back and forth between the computer and Arduino, but with the following code, I get an initial state of the Arduino and then the input stream ends and I never get anything from it again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class JSerialPortTest {

    static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort [] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        if (ports.length > 0) {
            serialPort = ports[0];
            System.out.println("Connected to " + serialPort.getSystemPortName());
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("No SerialPort detected.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Opened: " + serialPort.openPort());

        new Thread(new Runnable () {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
                while (true) {
                    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String input = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("   " + input);
                    }
                    else System.out.println("empty...");

                    try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

The initial output that I receive (and this is exactly what I want):

Y: 5    Button:     Y: 5    Button: 7   Y: 5    Button: Joystick X: -7  Y: 5    Button: Joystick X: -7  Y: 5    Button: Joystick X: -7  Y: 5    Button: Joystick X: -7  Y: 5    Button: Joystick X: -7  Y: 5    Button:

I was wondering if there is either something I'm doing wrong to read the outputs and they do come in periodically, or if there is a way to request another ouput like the one output I receive.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'I never get anything'? Exception occurred or loop forever? Post more logs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with programming lingo sometimes. I mean a loop forever. Everytime after the initial output, it loops through and it prints out "empty..." I've never had an exception thrown. Another log follows:

Comment: Connected to COM9
Opened: true
   Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: Joystick X: -7 Y: 5 Button: 
empty...
empty...
empty...

Comment: And then the "empty..." output repeats forever (as far as I know). Any ideas? Thank you for the help!

Comment: And actually now that I think about it, I don't know why it's printing out multiple joysticks. The Esplora only has one... It has four other buttons, but not joysticks...